# How to append element multiple times (slidingdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append 5 `li` elements when I click to div with class `moree`. 
It's working correctly, but when I click to more I want to add those buttons at the end of the list. Now the items are at the begging. 
Furturmore is there a way to append with effect slidingdown?
Here is my snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $(".moree").click(function () {
             $(this).closest('.content').append('<ol ><li>Title 2</li></ol>');
        });
   }  

});
```

```css
ol > li { 
   list-style:none; 
   padding-top:10px; 
   border:1px solid green;
   margin-top:10px;
}
.moree { 
   width:30px; 
   background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
    <ol>
    <li>title</li>
     <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
    </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `prepend(...` instead of `append(...`.

Comment: @DavidDomain is there a way to prepend with sliding down effect?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `div` as a direct child element of `ol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this? Its only slightly improved your example with slide down animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".moree").click(function () {
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {              
      $(this)
        .prev()
        .append('<li style="display:none">Title 2</li>')
        .children()
        .last()
        .hide()
        .delay(delay)
        .slideDown(400);
      delay += 400;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ol > li{ list-style:none; padding-top:10px; border:1px solid green;margin-top:10px;}
.moree{ width:30px; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
      <ol>
        <li>title</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the more button still remains at the first posistion . how can i move that end of appended li?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should move "moree" class outside of the ordered list.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
  <ol>
   <li>title</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
 </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After that, in the jquery, move the for loop inside of the click function.

For the sliding effect to achieve, first we have to hide the element that we have to append, and then we use "appendTo()" function to append to the parent element and then we can use the "show()" function to slide the appended list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.moree').on('click', function(){
            for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
                $('<li>Title 2</li>').hide().appendTo('ol').show("slow");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding 5 list items, you added a click event listener 5 times to the same element.

This is probably what you want instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".moree").on('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      $(this).closest('.content').find('ol').append('<li class="no-height">Title ' + i + '</li>');
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() { $('li.no-height').removeClass('no-height'); }, 5);
  });
})
```

```css
ol > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
ol > li.no-height {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.moree {
  width: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="content">
    <ol>
      <li>title</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: is there a way to append with sliding down effect?

Comment: You could do that using css transitions. I'll edit my answer to show how.

Comment: Edited. The "animation" now works as a transition - a technique you maybe have not yet known about.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this JQuery code Hope It helps you

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
       for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $(".moree").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.content').prepend('<ol ><li>Title 2</li>   
        </ol>');
        });
         }  

         })
```

try the below Fiddle 
[DemoFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/q93sq30s/)
hope it helps